# Convert DOC to PDF from Command Line

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line, docx, doc

Anyone recommend a DOC to PDF converter that can be run from the command line? It seems like an easy requirement, but I have been coming up short on free solutions.

Comment: I always do it with a bit of vbscript to automate Word. Word 2007/2010 can be augmented with a PDF export filter that works very well. Would that suffice?

Comment: I tried that solution. Problem is, this will be running on a server and I have been running into tons of problems doing that way. I was originally doing it in C# using the Word Interop. Thanks though.

Comment: OK, then you should pony up and get Aspose.Words I guess.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/393118/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-from-windows-command-line?newreg=731c209bd66443bba1de13bc0fe94eed

Answer (score 9):

I recommend the [OfficeToPDF](https://github.com/cognidox/OfficeToPDF) command line application.

```
C:\>OfficeToPDF.exe /bookmarks /print /verbose test.docx test.pdf
Converting test.docx to test.pdf
Converting with Word converter
Completed Conversion
C:\>
```

I used this solution to automate the PDF generating using ANT.

Comment: uses "Office's in-built PDF export features"

Comment: See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/394931/221041). In short, use `OfficeToPDF "c​​:\help.doc" "c:\output\help.pdf"`. Binaries here: https://github.com/cognidox/OfficeToPDF/releases.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate you are trying to do this from the command line but because you mentioned C#, the approach I use to is to first convert a doc to ps (PostScript) in C# which is relatively simple and well documented and then from the command line use [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) to convert to PDF. Pls don't underestimate the tool from the basic looking website - it is amazing.

Comment: How do you get from doc to ps? Doesn't sound very easy to me.

Comment: Awesome, im going to give this a look over

Comment: @David - you simply print to a PostScript printer (there is a default generic one in all flavours of Windows) - it is easy I assure you, however, I am at home (UK) and have sample code in my office. If you're interested I will post sample code into my answer tomorrow.

Comment: @David - see OP's comments where he mentions Interop which I noted in my answer was not his chosen solution but offered in conjuntion with a command line tool which was what the OP asked for. I stand by my answer and it seemd frm OP's comments to my answer that he likes the idea. Also, the approach may have have been around for a while but 5 years out of date - no - I disagree.